# correct usage of ignore_user_abort in php

Tags: php, performance

I'm making a script that would run in the background with ignore_user_abort however I would like to make a html form so the user can decide if he wants to run the script in the background or not. My question is: will ignore_user_abort work as intended if I define it at the end of the script? after I process the form sent by the user ? or it has to be at the beginning of the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ignore_user_abort`'s effect starts where the command is placed.

=> You should place it around the beginning of the script.

Otherwise you should consider add `set_time_limit(0);` as well.

[set_time_limit() info](https://www.php.net/set_time_limit)